# Partial View MVC 2 event function not defined

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-2, partial-views

I return the partial view with ajax function. Then in this partial view I have a dropdownlist and a gave an onchange event. The problem is that chrome shows that the function is not defined. I do not why it does not work. Need some help..
Here is dropdownlist:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
    <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProductCode, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Products"], new { id = "productSelect", onchange="OnProductChange"})%>
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
<% } %>
```

Script:

```
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.debug.js") %>" 
    type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.debug.js") %>" 
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function OnProductChange() {
    alert("Message");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add brackets onchange="OnProductChange()"

```
    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
    <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProductCode, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Products"], new { id = "productSelect", onchange="OnProductChange()"})%>
<input type="submit" value="Save" /> <% } %>
```